# CakePHP select input : is setting a display member and a value member possible?

Tags: arrays, cakephp, select, input

I have this form input:

```
echo $this->Form->input('category_id',array('label'=>'Cat&eacute;gorie','type'=>"select",'options'=>$categories,'empty'=>false));
```

Now, $category is filled with those informations:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [categories] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [nom] => Autre
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [categories] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [nom] => Véhicule
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [categories] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [nom] => Audio/video
            )

    )

)
```

I would like that the Select input shows only the "nom" field (name), but that it sends the ID when the form is submitted. Is that possible in CakePHP? I've been crawling through Google and CakePHP's doc and forums for a while without success :-/

Thank you in advance guys and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cakephp uses a single dimension array for select options. You change your your to single dimension with id as your key and nom as text of option tag and then pass it to options key:

```
$categories = Set::combine($categories,'{n}.categories.id','{n}.categories.nom');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should respect Cakephp conventions. Remplace "nom" by "name" in your database and cakephp will do it automatically if your associations have been well done.

Comment: I would do this, but sadly the conventions already established in my company won't let me do this. Thanks for the answer though.