# CakePHP omitting to send an input field and changing input value onSubmit?

Tags: javascript, arrays, cakephp, submit, hidden

I am on CakePHP 1.2 at the office and, following [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692728/cakephp-select-input-is-setting-a-display-member-and-a-value-member-possible/11692848), I would like to send the array key of the selected option in a `SELECT` input instead of sending its actual value. I have tried a few things with the `Model::beforeSave()` function, without success.

I am aware that the data posted by CakePHP does not include the whole array, but only the selected value.
Here is what the function looks like at the moment:

```
function beforeSave(){
    $this->Post->set('category_id', = array_keys($this->data['Annonce']['category_id']);
    # debug($this->data);
}
```

Would there be a way to store the array keys into an hidden input and changing this input value depending on the user's selected item in the `SELECT` input, and to also omit sending the user's input but still send the hidden value?

Comment: This is more of a JavaScript question than a PHP / CakePHP one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$categories = Set::combine($categories,'{n}.categories.id', '{n}.categories.nom');
```

This did it for me... CakePHP assigns the `array_keys()` values automatically to the `value` field of the input.